# a question about Fredholm operator decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Recently I was studying Lyapunov-Schmidt reduction method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov%E2%80%93Schmidt_reduction) . At the construction part , they are assuming a decomposition of the Banach spaces $X,Y$ related to the Fredholm operator $\partial_xf:X\to Y$ as a direct sum of a finite dimensional subspace and a closed subspace .

My question is : why this decomposition is possible ? Does the decomposition hold for any kind of linear operators or only Fredholm operators ? If the latter is true , then I want a detailed proof of this decomposition .

My apologies if this is a basic question . Since I am a newbie in theory of Fredholm operators and just know definitions of the aforesaid . Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

So Fredholm operator means you have finite (and hence closed, since all finite spaces are Banach) kernel and finite cokernel, i.e if $f:X\longrightarrow Y $ is fredholm then both $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ and $\mathrm{coker}(f) = Y/\mathrm{Im}(f)$ are both finite. Now you get to break $$X = \mathrm{ker}(f) \oplus X/  \mathrm{ker}(f)$$ and $$Y = \mathrm{coker}(f) \oplus \mathrm{Im}(f),$$ and one of the direct summands is finite in each case.